# Not able to get waitpid() to return correct WEXITSTATUS for error condition

Tags: c, waitpid, wexitstatus

I have a command and some input that when run on the command line will return an error, with an associated error code of 1:

```
$ foo bar
[some useful error message...]
$ echo $?
1
```

I am trying to catch this error code with `waitpid()`:

```
...
char *proc_cmd = "foo bar"
pid_t proc = popen4(proc_cmd, in_fd, out_fd, err_fd, POPEN4_FLAG_NONE);
...
if (waitpid(proc, &global_foo_status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED) == -1) {
    /* process failed */
}
...
pthread_create(&proc_thread, NULL, perform_foo_function, bar_data);
pthread_join(proc_thread, (void **) NULL);
...
```

My thread will run `perform_foo_function()` until there is no more `bar_data` to process, or until the process fails due to an error in the data:

```
static void * perform_foo_function (data *bar_data) {
    /* check before */
    if (WIFEXITED(global_foo_status)) {
        int exit_status = WEXITSTATUS(global_foo_status);
        if (exit_status != 0) 
            /* process failed */
    }

    /* do stuff with bar_data */
    while (bar_data) {
        /* causes error ... */
    }

    /* check after */
    if (WIFEXITED(global_foo_status)) {
        int exit_status = WEXITSTATUS(global_foo_status);
        if (exit_status != 0) 
            /* process failed */
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

My question is how to catch the error status of this process? In the course of debugging, the `WEXITSTATUS` is always zero, whether I purposefully create an error situation or provide legitimate input.

What am I misunderstanding about `waitpid()` and associated status code checks, and what changes should I make to get this to work?

**Follow-up**

The following code seems to work, without blocking:

```
...
char *proc_cmd = "foo bar"
pid_t global_foo_pid = popen4(proc_cmd, in_fd, out_fd, err_fd, POPEN4_FLAG_NONE);
...
if (waitpid(global_foo_pid, &global_foo_status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED) == -1) {
    /* process failed */
}
...
pthread_create(&proc_thread, NULL, perform_foo_function, bar_data);
pthread_join(proc_thread, (void **) NULL);
...

static void * perform_foo_function (data *bar_data) 
{
    /* do stuff with bar_data */
    while (bar_data) {
        /* causes error ... */
    }

    /* check after */
    if (WIFEXITED(global_foo_status)) {
        waitpid(global_foo_pid, &global_foo_status, WUNTRACED);
        int exit_status = WEXITSTATUS(global_foo_status);
        if (exit_status != 0) 
            /* process failed */
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I'm guessing that the "check after" `waitpid()` call doesn't hang because the process has already exited at this step.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things, here.

First, your `global_foo_status` variable will be updated after, and only after, a call to `waitpid()` or friends. In the code presented, you only call `waitpid()` once, before creating your thread. So all those `WIFEXITED` and `WEXITSTATUS` macros you're using are working on the same value of `global_foo_status` that you got on that initial call to `waitpid()`. This is almost certainly why you always see a value of zero when you're debugging, because you never get an updated value after your process terminates, and you're just checking that initial value over and over. If you want to check whether the process exited, you'll have to call `waitpid()` again, each time.

Second, `WIFEXITED` evaluates to true if the process terminated normally, but this is not the only way a process can terminate. There is another macro, `WIFSIGNALED` that will evaluate to true if the process was terminated due to the receipt of a signal. If you're only using `WIFEXITED` to check for termination, and your process gets abnormally terminated by a signal, you're going to be unsuccessfully checking forever. Better is to use the return from `waitpid()` to find out if the process died for any reason.

Your function should probably look more like this:

```
static void * perform_foo_function (data *bar_data) {

    /* check before */

    pid_t status = waitpid(global_foo_pid, &global_foo_status, WNOHANG);
    if ( status == -1 ) {
        perror("error calling waitpid()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if ( status == global_foo_pid ) {

        /*  Process terminated  */

        if ( WIFEXITED(global_foo_status) ) {

            /*  Process terminated normally  */

            int exit_status = WEXITSTATUS(global_foo_status);
            if ( exit_status ) {
                /*  Process failed  */

                return NULL;
            }
            else {
                /*  Process terminated normally and successfully  */

                return NULL;
            }
        }
        else {

            /*  Process terminated abnormally  */

                return NULL;
        }
    }

    /*  Process is still running if we got here  */

    /* do stuff with bar_data */

    while (bar_data) {
        /* causes error ... */
    }

    /*  Check after - if getting an error from doing stuff
        with bar_data implies the process should always
        shortly terminate, then you probably don't want
        WNOHANG in the following line.                       */

    status = waitpid(global_foo_pid, &global_foo_status, WNOHANG);
    if ( status == -1 ) {
        perror("error calling waitpid()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if ( status == global_foo_pid ) {

        /*  Process terminated  */

        if ( WIFEXITED(global_foo_status) ) {

            /*  Process terminated normally  */

            int exit_status = WEXITSTATUS(global_foo_status);
            if ( exit_status ) {
                /*  Process failed  */

                return NULL;
            }
            else {
                /*  Process terminated normally and successfully  */

               return NULL;
            }
        }
        else {
            /*  Process terminated abnormally  */

                return NULL;
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

That whole process check is a prime candidate for factoring out into a separate function, too.

If you have several threads all running `perform_foo_function()` at the same time, then `waitpid()` is only going to return appropriately in one of them. You'll probably want a separate variable, `global_foo_has_finished` or similar, that the threads can check before trying to call `waitpid()`. You'd also want to synchronize access to all those globals, or redesign so they're not necessary (you could pass `global_foo_pid` right into your thread function, for instance, and `global_foo_status` doesn't need to be global since it's never accessed anywhere else).